# SQL - Insert Stored Procedure Results into Temp Table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a fully working stored procedure grabbing data from different tables using joins. I am currently using the below SELECT statement to select the data I require:

```
SELECT 
   ClientReference, ReferenceNumber, Text3, 
   ReceiptDate, [dbo].[Complaint].[Description],
   ActionTaken, dbo.Category.Name, dbo.CategoryOption.FullName, 
   dbo.Complaint.AuditCreatedBy, 
   dbo.UserGroup.Name, dbo.Complaint.LoggedByUserId, 
   dbo.Complaint.LoggedByTime 
FROM
   dbo.Complaint
```

Now what I want to be able to do is insert this data into a temporary table. However, `INSERT INTO` does not work as I have two columns (resulting from my join) called `Name`.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT ... INTO #temp ..`?

Comment: Did you try INSERT INTO with a field list, making sure you have separate field names for each NAME returned from your proc?

Comment: FYI, that's not a valid `SELECT` statement.  I assume there's more to it?

Comment: Have you tried using aliases?

Answer (score 4):

Just alias one of the `Name` columns:

```
SELECT 
   ClientReference, 
   ReferenceNumber, 
   Text3, 
   ReceiptDate, 
   Complaint.Description,
   ActionTaken, 
   Category.Name As CategoryName, 
   CategoryOption.FullName, 
   Complaint.AuditCreatedBy, 
   UserGroup.Name, 
   Complaint.LoggedByUserId, 
   Complaint.LoggedByTime 
INTO #tempTable
FROM
   dbo.Complaint
   ...
```